# Enable Custom Actions in every Document Library (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, document-library, custom-actions

I have created a custom action in a document library using SharePoint Designer. My mission is to enable this custom action in every document library, is there any settings for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that with the help of WSP solution.
You need to create XML based Custom action for all the document library type.

Refer below examples for creating custom actions:

[Custom actions in SharePoint 2013](http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/custom-actions-in-sharepoint-2013.html)

[Creating SharePoint Ribbon Custom Actions with Visual Studio 2012](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2012/12/11/creating-sharepoint-ribbon-custom-actions-with-visual-studio-2012.aspx)

[How to Add Custom Ribbon Action on List/Libraries in SharePoint 2013](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Add-Custom-Ribbon-Action-on-ListLibraries-in-SharePoint-2013)

[How to: Create custom actions to deploy with apps for SharePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163954.aspx)

Comment: I'm not using visual studio 2012. I'm creating new document libraries using REST. Everytime i create a new document library i have to manually go into SharePoint designer where i create this custom action. I want to create it once in SharePoint designer and enable it in every document library that is created.